# [FBSDKLoginButton analyticsParameters]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-login, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm currently in the process of upgrading my FB SDK from `3.x` to `4.0.1`. I only use the FB Login for my app and for this functionality, I use `FBSDKLoginButton`. I followed each of the upgrade steps properly and manage to get it run several times but then afterwards it kept crashing and returning these error:

```
[FBSDKLoginButton analyticsParameters]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7feb70e89af0
```

#### My Implementation

In my `AppDelegate.m`

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{    
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    // I create my button using storyboard.
    [FBSDKLoginButton class];

    ...

    return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [FBSDKAppEvents activateApp];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{
    return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                          openURL:url
                                                sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                                       annotation:annotation];
}
```

In my `ViewController.h`

```
@interface SLLandingController : UIViewController <FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet FBSDKLoginButton *FBLoginButton;

@end
```

In my `ViewController.m`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    [self customizeViews];
    ...
    self.FBLoginButton.readPermissions = @[@"public_profile", @"email", @"user_friends"];
    self.FBLoginButton.delegate = self;
}
```

I also have implemented all the prerequisite as follows:

- Linked both `FBSDKCoreKit` & `FBSDKLoginKit` properly.
- Setup `.plist` files with FB App ID & Display Name.
- Implement the `loginButton:didCompleteWithResult:error` delegate method

Traced it with breakpoint to `CoreKit > FBSDKButton.m`

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
  // automatic impression tracking if the button conforms to FBSDKButtonImpressionTracking
  if ([self conformsToProtocol:@protocol(FBSDKButtonImpressionTracking)]) {
    ...
    // It breaks here
    NSDictionary *parameters = [(id<FBSDKButtonImpressionTracking>)self analyticsParameters];
    ...
  }
  [super layoutSubviews];
}
```

Any ideas on what might cause this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the line `[FBSDKLoginButton class];` should be removed from AppDelegate.m since you are adding the class in the storyboard. Try removing this and see if the crash still occurs.

In the [Facebook Login for iOS](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/v2.3) it says for that piece of code:

> This loads FBSDKLoginButton before the view displays..

I don't believe that is necessary when the FBSDKLoginButton class is already added through the Interface Builder.